# How can I split a street address in the below formats in unix or R or grep or awk?

Tags: regex, r, awk, split, substring

I have a file with Italian street name and address, I have to split the column of address to street name and street number. The catch is the addresses have two or three string and then numbers or number some times have character as well e.g 15/a
Some of them have adress like 12-Maggio 23 and my split should be first column 12-maggio and second column 23.

Below are the format of the file

```
Street.adress
Falcone N. 1
Fortunato Giustino 2
Pisacane 3
Fabrizio De Andre' 8
S. Satta 7
Agnesi 16
Volturno Cigni 80
Montepenice 6
Cucchiari 15
Molinetto Di Lorenteggio 15/T 7
Don Minzoni 15
Senigallia 4
Milano 38/A
L. Da Vinci 13/A
27-Novembre 9
```

Output should be in 2 separate columns

```
Falcone N.  1
 Fortunato Giustino 2
 Pisacane   3
 Fabrizio De Andre' 8
 S. Satta   7
 Agnesi 16
 Volturno Cigni 80
 Montepenice 6  6
 Cucchiari  15
 Molinetto Di Lorenteggio    15/T 7
 Don Minzoni    15
 Senigallia 4
 Milano 38/A
 L. Da Vinci    13/A
 27-Novembre    9
```

How can I achieve this, I have tried the excel formulas and also unsplit but does not work. I have tried in R the below code but it fails, so how can I do this?

```
for (i in 1:nrow (df)) {

  new_df [i,"Street.Name"] <- unlist(strsplit (df[["Street.Addresses"]], " ")[i])[1]
  new_df [i,"Street.Number"] <- paste (unlist(strsplit (df[["Street.Addresses"]], " ")[i])[-1], collapse = " ")

}
```

Tried

```
df <- gsub("$([0-9]+ +)?(.*)", "\\1\t\\2", df)
```

Nothing works. Any leads

Comment: is there a chance that a street name has number and text but with out the "-"? you mention 2 street names with numbers and both have the "-"

Answer (score 6):

This regular expression combined with `gsub()` and `strsplit()` works on the data you provided.

The trick here is that I first insert a `\t` at the location where I want to split the string, then use `strsplit()` with `\t` as the separator.

```
x <- read.table(sep = "\n",
                header = TRUE,
                quote = "\"",
                text = "Street.adress
Falcone N. 1
Fortunato Giustino 2
Pisacane 3
Fabrizio De Andre' 8
S. Satta 7
Agnesi 16
Volturno Cigni 80
Montepenice 6
Cucchiari 15
Molinetto Di Lorenteggio 15/T 7
Don Minzoni 15
Senigallia 4
Milano 38/A
L. Da Vinci 13/A
27-Novembre 9"
)


pattern <- "(.*?) +(\\d+.*)"

z <- gsub(pattern, "\\1\t\\2", x[[1]])
unlist(
  strsplit(z, "\t")
)
```

The results:

```
 [1] "Falcone N."               "1"                       
 [3] "Fortunato Giustino"       "2"                       
 [5] "Pisacane"                 "3"                       
 [7] "Fabrizio De Andre'"       "8"                       
 [9] "S. Satta"                 "7"                       
[11] "Agnesi"                   "16"                      
[13] "Volturno Cigni"           "80"                      
[15] "Montepenice"              "6"                       
[17] "Cucchiari"                "15"                      
[19] "Molinetto Di Lorenteggio" "15/T 7"                  
[21] "Don Minzoni"              "15"                      
[23] "Senigallia"               "4"                       
[25] "Milano"                   "38/A"                    
[27] "L. Da Vinci"              "13/A"                    
[29] "27-Novembre"              "9"
```

---

PS. Answer edited to deal with the fact there was a quote `'` in the input data. To deal with this, you have to set `quote = "\""` as an argument to `read.table()` otherwise some lines will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in string format, and the number are always separated by a empty digit, just use:

strsplit(dataframe$address_collum, " ")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner with `strsplit`

```
strsplit(x$Street.adress, " (?<=\\D{4})(?=\\d+.*)", perl=TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "Falcone N." "1"         
#[[2]]
#[1] "Fortunato Giustino" "2"                 
#[[3]]
#[1] "Pisacane" "3"       
#[[4]]
#[1] "Fabrizio De Andre'" "8"                 
#[[5]]
#[1] "S. Satta" "7"       
#[[6]]
#[1] "Agnesi" "16"    
#[[7]]
#[1] "Volturno Cigni" "80"            
#[[8]]
#[1] "Montepenice" "6"          
#[[9]]
#[1] "Cucchiari" "15"       
#[[10]]
#[1] "Molinetto Di Lorenteggio" "15/T 7"                  
#[[11]]
#[1] "Don Minzoni" "15"         
#[[12]]
#[1] "Senigallia" "4"         
#[[13]]
#[1] "Milano" "38/A"  
#[[14]]
#[1] "L. Da Vinci" "13/A"       
#[[15]]
#[1] "27-Novembre" "9"
```

To put that into 2 columns, you could do this:

```
splt <- strsplit(x$Street.adress, " (?<=\\D{4})(?=\\d+.*)", perl=TRUE)
matrix(unlist(splt), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

This does make a few assumptions about text that Andrie's solution does not make:

- Assumes character (not factor) data,
- No more than 3 non-digit characters (`\\D`) come between address digits (e.g. "Molinetto Di Lorenteggio 15/TT 7" won't work. You'd have to change `{4}` to `{5}` to make it work).
- The `\\D{4}` also means that if you find a digit character after a space, there need to be at least 4 non-digit characters preceding it to split properly (e.g. It works for "Elm 1" but not "El 1").